# dynamic navigation links in main application and mounted rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am working on a project to use rails engine whose views will be used inside of the main applications layout . My main application layout is made up of navigation links which is sort of like breadcrumbs which provides context to the user of how they reached that particular page.

So the question i had is : If i access the view of a mounted engine which renders the view inside of the main applications layout. how to make the navigation links which is part of the main application dynamic ?

Code Examples

```
module Engine
 class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController

 end
end
```

Engines application controller uses main applications application controller which means that main applications layout will be used to render action views.

Main application application layout (using haml)

```
%html.no-js
 %head
  %title Main App
  %body                                                                
   .body-content
     %main
    = yield :navigation
      .main-content
        = yield
      = site_footer
```

If you notice my application layout i have yield :navigation. This is rendered whenever there is a content_for method is used to define it. For example : lets say we are rendering an index action from one my main applications controller the haml would look like this

index.html.haml

```
- content_for :navigation do
   %a.active{href: root_path}
   %a{href: some_path}
end

%h1 Index page.
```

So the main question i have is if i render my engines controller action views the engine does not know how to build the navigation links for the main application. Is there any way that i can let main application define this and let the engine render the navigation links somehow.

Comment: You'll have to provide some code samples - I can give you info about Rails Engines, but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: RichPeck i have updated the question . I have tried to be as clear as  possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the main_app  helper in your links.

```
%a.active{href: main_app.root_path}
```

Will allways reference you main apps root. Likewise

```
%a.active{href: my_engine.root_path}
```

Will always reference the engines root.

Or as said in the link below

> If you wish to reference the application inside the engine in a similar way, use the main_app helper:
>
> `<%= link_to "Home", main_app.root_path %>`
>
> If you were to use this inside an engine, it would always go to the >application's root. If you were to leave off the main_app "routing proxy" >method call, it could potentially go to the engine's or application's >root, depending on where it was called from.

For fore information see:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes

/rpkn